# Why does Macro Stop Running When New Workbook Opened?

Tags: vba, excel, macros, save

I'm using the following snippet of code to save the spreadsheet, make it value-only and re-save it. However the workbook opens then the macro stops running.

Why is this? And how do I stop it? I've tried setting `ScreenUpdating = False` to no avail.

```
Sub saveReport()
    Dim nwkbk As Workbook
    Dim thsWkbk As Workbook

    Set thsWkbk = ThisWorkbook

    nwkbkPath = thsWkbk.Path & "\x. Archive\" & Format(Date, "YYYY-MM-DD - ") & thsWkbk.Name

    ApplicationDisplayAlerts = False
    thsWkbk.SaveCopyAs nwkbkPath

    Set nwkbk = Workbooks.Open(nwkbkPath, False)

    For w = 1 To nwkbk.Sheets.Count
        nwkbk.Sheets(w).UsedRange = nwkbk.Sheets(w).UsedRange.Value
    Next w

    For wsp = 1 To nwkbk.Sheets.Count
        nwkbk.Sheets(wsp).Protect Password:="SettleDownBenny"
    Next wsp

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    nwkbk.Save

    nwkbk.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: I think you have an error with your `nwkbkPath = thsWkbk.Path & "\x. Archive\" & Format(Date, "YYYY-MM-DD - ") & thsWkbk.Name` , do you have a folder "x. Archive" nested under the current Path of this Excel file ?

Comment: have you some event handlers in your _original_ workbook? they would be copied into the new workbook and interfere with the running macro: try saving it as plain xlsx file, hence with no macro surviving

Comment: @user3598756 Correct. I have an AutoOpen method that runs as soon as the spreadsheet is opened. Good pick up. How do you save a copy, but select the format? Excel is obscenely ridiculous to manage when coupled with VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer:** Your macro stops running because it is saved as an `xlsm`. Which may have event handlers start when it opens, and thus stop the original macro. UPDATE: In this case it was the `Auto_Open` method which runs automatically when the `xlsm` is opened.

**How To Solve Your Problem:** Use the [`Copy()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193304.aspx) method of `Worksheets` object to copy all worksheets from a workbook to a new one (originally just for the format as the formulae will not work). Then you'llneed to copy these as values alone using the `.Value` attribute to ensure all values verbatim are copied.Then the `SaveAs()` method is called to save it.

Code is as follows:

```
Sub saveReport()
Dim nwkbkPath As String
Dim w As Long


Set thsWorkbook = ThisWorkbook


With thsWorkbook '<--| reference 'ThisWorkbook'
    nwkbkPath = .Path & "\x. Archive\" & Format(Date, "YYYY-MM-DD - ") & GetName(.Name) '<--| use only the "strict" name (no extension) of ThisWorkbook
    .Sheets.Copy '<--| copy all worksheets from 'thsWkbk' to a new workbook, which also becomes the 'ActiveWorkbook'
End With


On Error GoTo ErrHandler
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Set nwWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook

For w = 1 To nwWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    nwWorkbook.Sheets(w).UsedRange = thsWorkbook.Sheets(w).UsedRange.Value
Next w


For w = 1 To nwWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    nwWorkbook.Sheets(w).Protect Password:="SettleDownBenny"
Next w
nwWorkbook.SaveAs nwkbkPath


ActiveWorkbook.Close


ErrHandler:
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub


Function GetName(wbName As String) As String
    GetName = Left(wbName, InStrRev(wbName, ".") - 1)
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

use [`Copy()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193304.aspx) method of `Worksheets` object to copy all worksheets from a workbook to a new one, on which to perform all needed operations and finally call `SaveAs()` method

as follows

```
Option Explicit

Sub saveReport()
    Dim nwkbkPath As String
    Dim w As Long

    With ThisWorkbook '<--| reference 'ThisWorkbook'
        nwkbkPath = .Path & "\x. Archive\" & Format(Date, "YYYY-MM-DD - ") & GetName(.name) '<--| use only the "strict" name (no extension) of ThisWorkbook
        .Sheets.Copy '<--| copy all worksheets from 'thsWkbk' to a new workbook, which also becomes the 'ActiveWorkbook'
    End With

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    With ActiveWorkbook '<--| reference the ActiveWorkbook
        For w = 1 To .Sheets.Count
            .Sheets(w).UsedRange = .Sheets(w).UsedRange.Value
        Next w

        For w = 1 To .Sheets.Count
            .Sheets(w).Protect Password:="SettleDownBenny"
        Next w
        .SaveAs nwkbkPath
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.Close

ErrHandler:
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub

Function GetName(wbName As String) As String
    GetName = Left(wbName, InStrRev(wbName, ".") - 1)
End Function
```

where I also made some little refactoring of your original code

Comment: I've unaccepted because it actually destroys a lot of the data and does not save it as a value. The `#NAME?` error is rampant in this macro's pasted values. I'll see if I can edit your answer and I'll re-accept it when it copies values.

Comment: It's because in the copying process any custom functions I have created get removed by saving as an `xlsx` resulting in the `#NAME?` error.

Comment: The custom function issue wasn't specified in your _original_ question, thus my answer can't be asked to handle it. As per this site rules you should accept it as it solves the _original_ question and post a new one for the new issue.

Comment: May I edit it with the code that works, and add the answer to the question which is actually contained in your comment above?

Comment: I would also argue that if I want a function I want it to work in all circumstances.

Comment: P.S. I want to accept it but I want it to be the best answer for the question.

Comment: You may edit it and it would be reviewed before being accepted. As for the "best solution" I don't get you: my answer solved the _original_ question and is the only one... so where's the point not to accept it? See, the "one post-> one issue-> one answer, new issue->new post-" is a rule not to have post growing endlessly and having people clearly follow what's going on. you may want to [take a tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) for a better explanation of this